# Can't seem to understand complex polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm studying CS and we have questions about polymorphism that I cant wrap my mind around. Here is an example:

```
public class AA{
    public AA(){
        foo();
    }
    private void foo() {
        System.out.print("AA::foo ");
        goo();
    }
    public void goo(){
        System.out.print("AA::goo ");
    }
}

public class BB extends AA{
    public BB(){
        foo();
    }
    public void foo(){
        System.out.print("BB:foo ");
    }
    public void goo(){
        System.out.print("BB::goo ");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Code goes here
    }
}
```

When in void main i add the line:

```
AA a = new BB();
```

it goes first AA constructor prints AA:foo but then goo() sends it to BB's goo, why so?

Simple polymorphism such as "Animal -> cat/spider/dog" is easy to understand but when it comes to this I'm just lost. Can you guys give me any tips how to read this code? What are the rules are?

**EDIT**: there is no `@Override` annotation because this is a question from an exam.

Comment: it calls super()

Comment: the very first thing a constructor does, is calling the constructor of it's parent class (even if you don't specifically write that call). It's send to B's goo() because you instantiate an instance of B

Comment: What's the output you are getting?

Comment: 'Simple polymorphism such as "Animal -> cat/spider/dog"' is always abused to explain object-orientation. In reality hierarchies like this seldom occur and if they do, it's probably a bad piece of code. Try to avoid subclassing concrete classes, instead use interfaces where you can and instead of extending something always first consider if you cannot 'collaborate' with it (e.g. by defining it as a field)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Explanation

```
public class AA {

    private void foo() { ... }
    ^^^^^^^

}
```

Polymorphism is not applied to `private` methods. A subclass does not inherit `private` methods, so they cannot be overridden:

> A class `C` inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods `m` (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all of the following are true:
>
> - `m` is a member of the direct superclass of `C`.
> - **`m` is `public`, `protected`, or declared with package access in the same package as `C`.**
> - No method declared in `C` has a signature that is a [subsignature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) of the signature of `m`.
>
> <sup>[Java Language Specification - 8.4.8. Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)</sup>

Therefore, the `foo()` call from the `A` constructor doesn't invoke `BB#foo`, it calls `AA#foo`.

But the `goo()` call within `AA#foo` refers to the overridden method `BB#goo`. Here, with `public` methods, method overriding and polymorphism were applied.

---

It's a bit tricky, so I would recommend you put the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation everywhere it's supposed to be.

```
public class BB extends AA {

    @Override   // it doesn't compile - no overriding here
    public void foo() { ... }
    @Override   // it does override
    public void goo() { ... }

}
```

It also might be helpful to detect another problem:

> Programmers occasionally **overload** a method declaration when they mean to **override** it, leading to subtle problems. The annotation type `Override` supports early detection of such problems.
>
> If a method declaration in type `T` is annotated with `@Override`, but the method does not override from `T` a method declared in a supertype of `T`, or is not override-equivalent to a public method of `Object`, then a compile-time error occurs.
>
> <sup>[Java Language Specification - 9.6.4.4. `@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.4)</sup>

### Illustration

> If a constructor body **does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class `Object`**, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation `super();`, an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.
>
> <sup>[Java Language Specification - 8.8.7. Constructor Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)</sup>

To put it simply,

```
public BB() {
    foo();
}
```

turns into

```
public BB() {
    super();
    foo();
}
```

Keeping `super();` in mind, we can make the next illustration:

```
new BB()
        AA()                       // super(); -> AA constructor
                A#foo()            // private method call 
                        B#goo()    // polymorphic method call
        BB()                       // BB constructor
                B#foo()            // plain method call
```

Comment: Might be worth explicitly mentioning that unlike `AA#foo`; `AA#goo` is public, as it's easy to miss and can cause confusion if not noticed.

Comment: TIL! Coming from C++ that's unexpected, although so much more logical.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think there are arguments for C++'s decision to call the virtual functions of the class being constructed, and not some overridden version. Most importantly, `BB::goo()` may do things which are unexpected or impossible in the context of an `AA`'s construction, for example access as of yet uninitialized members of `BB`. The author of `AA` cannot know or protect against that, which means that *later code (from derived classes) makes code in `AA` buggy.* That is certainly unexpected.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: **Nope**. There is a special rule with regard to the handling of virtual methods during construction and destruction. What happens is that during the construction of the `AA` sub-object of `BB`, the virtual pointer is that of an `AA` object, and only when `AA`'s constructor has been executed is the virtual pointer switched to that of a `BB` object. Thus, calling `foo()` in `AA::AA()` would result in `AA::goo()` being called. Which opens up an other issue (calling pure virtual methods), hopefully your implementation is nice enough to throw in this case.

Comment: this is partially a wrong reference to the JLS `A class does not inherit private or static methods from its superinterfaces` - its about *interfaces*, but you are talking about classes. static methods **are** inherited from superclasses, but they are not overridable.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko also when you say that these are not inherited is wrong too, since statics are inherited, it needs proper fixes. It also would be cool, if you would link the actual JLS parts about constructor order

Comment: @MatthieuM. What you describe is exactly what I meant. Calling `BB::goo()` from `AA`'s constructor (as happens in C#, and apparently Java) is not good, imho, for the reason stated. Btw, the C++ compiler can see it if  `AA::goo()` is pure virtual since that is in `AA`'s declaration which must be available when a `BB` is constructed, and must not compile.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Unfortunately, it's hard to know if `AA::goo()` is indirectly called from `AA::AA()`; Turing completeness and all that; that's why it's undefined behavior to call a pure-virtual from a constructor (or destructor).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Is it logical? The `BB` part hasn't been constructed yet. I am not a Java developer, but when I read the question my first thought was "Java is buggy here".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I find both error-prone, for different reasons. In Java you get default-initialized members (0 for integrals, null for objects) where the class invariant may assume they can never be 0/null and in C++ you call pure virtual methods. Personally, I think both are wrong, and the only right approach is that *constructors should not run code*: that is, constructors should look like C's designated initializers, so that there is no chance to observe a "partially constructed" object. If you need special code, you can after create a static method to create your instance.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: _"in C++ you call pure virtual methods"_ Not so; in fact it's impossible to do so. What you call is the override in the most derived class at that point in construction. More generally though I agree neither is perfect, albeit for different reasons

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Most compilers implement *simple* warnings to prevent you from calling a pure virtual method from a constructor (if you directly invoke it); but those warnings are not perfect. And therefore [it is perfectly possible to accidentally call a pure virtual method from a constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/329d09d142e950db).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It is literally impossible to call a pure virtual member function (C++ does not have "methods") from anywhere - the fact that your program aborted when you tried to is proof of that. The exception text is misleading unfortunately. However you are absolutely right to say that a call will be attempted, if the override in the most derived class at that point in construction happens to be pure virtual.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: In fact, sometimes a compiler will know statically whether this is the case, because it's still an error even if the pure virtual member function has a definition (which is possible!), because the class knows about all of its bases, and because the class knows that any hypothetical more-deriving class is irrelevant. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ So, in a simple case, you will get a warning (e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce662026a0c37ecb). However it cannot know in general if the call happens via some other intermediate member function (e.g. your case) and so doesn't seem to bother even if the intermediate definition is readily available. Which is kind of it...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So... we are in violent agreement and just have a different definition of call. I meant "call" as in "attempt to call", not as in "is executed" :D

Answer (score 2):

It's explained very well in the official docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

So, the Java compiler is adding super() without args for you.

In fact, if the class you are extending doesn't have a default constructor you will be required to call this constructor with args before.

---

Otherwise, the reason why `AA:goo` is not being called is because is override by `BB` even if it doesn't have the `@Override` annotation, if you want to see that call you need to use super(); in your b:goo method. In fact, the foo is not override because it private so it's not possible to override it, if you try to add the annotation @Override you'll se you have a compilation failure.

Comment: There's also additional trickery due to `A::foo()` being `private` and `goo()` not.

Comment: @Kayaman nice one!. There is even more underlying trickery! See my answer ;-D

Answer (score 1):

AA::foo() is private so AA::foo() and BB::foo() aren't the same.

```
new BB()
```

will call AA::Constructor first, calling AA::foo().

AA::foo() call goo() and since you instantiated BB class it'll be BB::goo().

Please use "override" keyword on method when you want to do something like this

Answer (score 1):

There is also a serious design flaw in the example code: it is calling an overridable method from a constructor. This means that object BB might not be fully initialized at the time that this method is called on it. For example:

```
public class AA{

    public AA(){
        foo();
    }

    private void foo() {
        System.out.print("AA::foo ");
        goo();
    }

    public void goo(){
        System.out.print("AA::goo ");
    }
}

public class BB extends AA{

    private Date timestamp;

    public BB() {
        super();
        foo();
        timestamp = new Date();
    } 

    public void foo() {
        System.out.print("BB:foo ");
    }

    public void goo() {
        // goo() gets called before timestamp is initialized 
        // causing a NullPointerException
        System.out.print("BB::goo " + timestamp.getYear());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        AA obj = new BB();
    }
}
```

Remember this: NEVER CALL AN OVERRIDABLE METHOD FROM A CONSTRUCTOR (even not indirectly as in this example)

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is Simple yet Confusing at times when we use different set of names [Which is the case here].

Polymorphism is basically a Parent Child Relationship. Key here is, **if you are trying hard to place the names of the classes, use yourself instead** i.e. give comment line next to class names as below

```
public class AA{} //your Parent name
public class BB extends AA{} // yourself i.e. your name
```

When it comes to the code like this, `AA a = new BB();` , decode the code as below:

BB is you, AA is your parent.

`new` keyword is with YOU(i.e. BB), so a new object of YOU would be created or born. In order to for YOU to born, without your parents(i.e. AA), you cannot exist and so, first they will be born or created (i.e. AA constructor would run). Once your Parents (i.e. AA)  are created, then it is time for YOU to born(i.e. BB constructor would run).

In your example,

```
public AA(){
        foo(); -- line A
    }
    private void foo() {
        System.out.print("AA::foo ");
        goo(); -- line B
    }
    public void goo(){
        System.out.print("AA::goo "); -- line C
    }
```

As I told earlier, **Line A** would be called when you say  `AA a = new BB();` as **Line A** is in Constructor of AA, **Line A** calls foo() method and so the control lands in foo(), prints "AA::foo " and executes **Line B**. **Line B** calls goo() method and so on it reaches **Line C**. After **Line C** is executed, there is nothing left to execute in AA constructor (i.e. Object is created) and so the control flows down to the child Constructor ( As parent is created, it is time for the child to born) and so the child Constructor would be called next.

For Students/Beginners, I strongly recommend to go through **Head First Java** Edition. It really helps you in laying the Java Foundation Strong.